# Execution "df" command on AIX with the bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, aix, ksh

it's very strange that when I am executing df command on AIX with bash like 
*bash -c "df /"* I suppose it will be executed like on Linux, but still the result is same like korn shell. Please give me explanation to this. How can I somehow to be sure that *df* command output will be same on AIX and on Linux. Before my solution was installing bash on AIX. Now I cannot find any option beside rewrite new script for AIX

Answer (score 0):

AIX is and always was a system with its own flavor, so output of certain commands may be surprising.

If I understood you correctly and you're looking to get normal Linux output for `df`, then you should install `coreutils` package that is available as a part of AIX Toolbox for Linux - it is available [from IBM website](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/).

Please note, that GNU version of utilities would be available under /opt/freeware or /usr/linux/bin/, so you should set your path appropriately.